# How to show the menu bar in Thunar in Xubuntu 15.10?

Tags: xubuntu, filemanager, thunar, menu-bar

I accidentally hid the menu bar in the Thunar file manager, how can I make it visible again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

This shortcut is shown in the `View menu`.